# Scripting stdin and reading result of PowerShell script from batch

Tags: powershell

I have a version control system (VisualSVN) which can run a pre-commit-hook.  I think it uses `cmd.exe` as the interpreter.

My hook currently does this (checking for minimum message length):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET REPOS=%1
SET TXN=%2
SET SVNLOOK="$VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnlook.exe"

%SVNLOOK% log -t %TXN% %REPOS% | findstr .......... > nul
IF %errorlevel% gtr 0 (goto ERROR_TOO_SHORT)

goto NORMAL_EXIT

:ERROR_TOO_SHORT
echo Commit message too short 1>&2
exit 1

:NORMAL_EXIT
exit 0
```

I want to add a regex check.  The message should meet at least one of these two expressions in order to be parsed by some bash scripts.

```
\[((Issue|Resolves|Closes|Solves)[:=]\s?)?#?([0-9]+)\]
\[[nN]o?-?[uU](ser)?-?[iI](mpact)?\]
```

Unforatunately, I'm reading that these are too complicated for `findstr`, so I need to invoke PowerShell.

A powershell expression that works is:

```
[bool](  <Get stdin here> | 
  Select-String -CaseSensitive -Quiet 
    -Pattern '\[(((Issue|Resolves|Closes|Solves)[:=]\s?)?#?([0-9]+))|([nN]o?-?[uU](ser)?-?[iI](mpact)?)\]
)
```

Here it is in action:

```
> $good1 = [bool](echo "[NUI] test message" | 
>>  Select-String -CaseSensitive -Quiet 
>>    -Pattern '\[(((Issue|Resolves|Closes|Solves)[:=]\s?)?#?([0-9]+))|([nN]o?-?[uU](ser)?-?[iI](mpact)?)\]
>> )
> $good2 = [bool](echo "[Closes=1234] test message" | 
>>    Select-String -CaseSensitive -Quiet 
>>      -Pattern '\[(((Issue|Resolves|Closes|Solves)[:=]\s?)?#?([0-9]+))|([nN]o?-?[uU](ser)?-?[iI](mpact)?)\]
>> )
> $bad = [bool](echo "This is an invalid message" | 
>>    Select-String -CaseSensitive -Quiet 
>>      -Pattern '\[(((Issue|Resolves|Closes|Solves)[:=]\s?)?#?([0-9]+))|([nN]o?-?[uU](ser)?-?[iI](mpact)?)\]
>> )
> echo $good1
True
> echo $good2
True
> echo $bad
False
```

How can I integrate that into my script?  I need to figure out how to pipe the output of `%SVNLOOK%` into PowerShell, invoke the command, set the exit code, and then use that exit code in my script.

I tried this simplified example that checks if stdin contains an `H`, but PowerShell is obviously not `bash`:

```
> echo "Hello" | PowerShell -Command "[bool]([Console]:In | Select-String -CaseSensitive -Quiet -Pattern 'H')"
> echo %errorlevel%
0
> echo " ello" | PowerShell -Command "[bool]([Console]:In | Select-String -CaseSensitive -Quiet -Pattern 'H')"
> echo %errorlevel%
0 <-- Expected 1
```

I tried a few things here, and I think `[Console]::In` is not forwarding `Hello` to `Select-String`.

Comment: You can use the `%SVNLOOK%` variable directly in PowerShell without piping it: `Select-String -InputObject $env:SVNLOOK …`

Comment: It's useful to know that PowerShell inherits its parent's environment.  How would I add the arguments to `-InputObject` and how would I convert the result into something I can use in the other script?

Comment: Extending from your own answer, this should work: `PowerShell -Command "exit ! [bool](Select-String -InputObject $env:SVNLOOK -Pattern 'H' -Quiet)"`. You may prefer this style: `PowerShell -Command "exit ! [bool]($env:SVNLOOK |Select-String -Pattern 'H' -Quiet)"` … The `-InputObject` parameter can be bound to pipeline input, so both ways should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.

First,  to get the stdin of PowerShell, you need to use `$Input`.  Still not sure if that's an environment variable, a pipe, or a process.

```
> echo "Hello" | PowerShell -Command "[bool]($Input | Select-String -Pattern 'H' -Quiet)"
True
```

Next, we need to set `%errorlevel%` with that output.  We can do that with `exit` and using the `!` operator to return a match as `0`:

```
> echo "Hello" | PowerShell -Command "exit ! [bool]($Input | Select-String -Pattern 'H' -Quiet)"
> echo %errorlevel%
0
```

The negative also works:

```
> echo " ello" | PowerShell -Command "exit ! [bool]($Input | Select-String -Pattern 'H' -Quiet)"
> echo %errorlevel%
1
```

Comment: `$Input` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4#input).